# Sqlplus In spool file header are short cutted according to the max no of characters in the row.

Tags: csv, header, sqlplus, spool

```
set term off
set echo off
set pagesize 50000
set trimout on
set trimspool on
set feedback off
set linesize 30000
set colsep "|"
set underline off
set heading on
set Newpage None
spool file.csv
@sqlfile.sql
spool off;
```

My query results has around 20 column headers , some letters are missing in headers . for eg if the header is STATE and the row values are like qw,we,er like this then the header is just ST. It adjusts according to the max no of strings in row.

Comment: You'll need to show what your sqlfile.sql is as it's likely to be some formatting within that e.g. Col STATE format A2.

Comment: no it doesnt have any formatting . It jus has sql query alone

Comment: Can someone pls help me in this ?